# Create page like custom post type list in Wordpress

Tags: archives

I would like to know if I can have a page in WP that works like `archive.php` for my custom post type.

I would like that it works like when in `Settings -> Reading` I choose an static page like `Posts page`.

Thank you!

Comment: If your post type has `has_archive` set to `true`, then these get created dynamically. Go to `http://yourdomain.com/post-type-slug` and you'll see it. The template that's used will be determined by the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, but then I don't have the custom post meta that I have in a static Page :(

Comment: Maybe give https://github.com/humanmade/page-for-post-type a go.

Comment: I tried that plugin but doesn't work. Don't worry, I will do creating a shortcode. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set `has_archive` to `false` when you register the CPT. Then, create a Page with the same slug. So if your CPT is "mycpt" then create a Page at http://example.com/mycpt/.

From there, set up a custom Page template to act like an archive, but you can also (optionally) add content in the Page itself to appear above or below the individual CPT posts. You'll also be able to add all the regular Page attributes like postmeta.